# Cannot delete shared files

Tags: macos, vmware

I have Vmware Fusion 4 on my Mac. I used it for work for awhile and had windows 7 installed and was joined to a AD Domain. When I left the company I had to un-join it from the Domain. Now, I cannot delete files that were shared between the mac (iOS 6) and Windows. How can I change the permissions so I can clean up my mac?

Comment: Could you perhaps clean up the versions and post a picture of what VMWare's file sharing settings are currently set to? It's not clear if you want to just delete the whole Windows 7 VM or the files that fusion has stored in your Mac's home folder. Also - what is iOS 6 doing in the text?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I meant OSX. Lion to be exact.I just want to get the files off my system. I am thinking it is a permissions problem, but not sure how to solve it. I would think the apple side would be the best option, but not sure of the commands. ( I'm a Microsoft admin. Unix is not my strong point) Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to turn off folder sharing between the VM and the Mac using Fusion's "sharing" settings and then shut down the VM.  After that, you should be able (from the Mac Finder) to move the shared folder to the Trash.  You may need to type an administrator password in the process, but that would be an administrator for the Mac host, which is presumably you.

If that doesn't work, please provide more details, such as where the files are as seen by the VM, where the files are as seen by the Mac, and what happens when you try to delete the files from the Mac.